# Pkcs1 padding while signing with bouncy castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I have the following c# Bouncy Castle code to sign some data in C# using RSA/SHA512. Can any tell me how I can also apply Pkcs1 padding in this process?

```
using (var txtreader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(_certificatePath)))
{
    var keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

    var key = keyPair.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;
    ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA512withRSA");
    sig.Init(true, key);

    sig.BlockUpdate(requestToSign, 0, requestToSign.Length);
    byte[] signature = sig.GenerateSignature();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PKCS#1 is actually the only padding algorithm used for RSA-SHA512 signing.

Check [RFC 4051](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4051.txt):

> 2.3.4.  RSA-SHA512
>
> This implies the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding algorithm [RFC3447] as described in section 2.3.1, but with the ASN.1 BER SHA-512 algorithm designator prefix.

You could also check [BouncyCastle source code](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/signers/RsaDigestSigner.cs). `RsaDigestSigner` creates the instance of `Pkcs1Encoding` without any conditions or configuration:

```
private readonly IAsymmetricBlockCipher rsaEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaBlindedEngine());
```

You could also check used implementation under debug:

[image]

So answering the question:

> Can any tell me how I can also apply Pkcs1 padding in this process?

No additional actions should be taken. Pkcs1 is the only possible padding algorithm for RSA-SHA512 signing.